# Update even though using constraints

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, foreign-keys, primary-key, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to update a value (small spelling error) in the SQL Server 2014 database.

I do like this:

```
update t_Table set funID = 'References' where funID = 'Referencies'
```

When doing this I get the error

```
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_t_Table_Language_t_Table". The conflict occurred in database "db", table "dbo.t_Table".
```

If updating the foreign key, I get a similar error.

Is there any way to update all values at the same time?
I have a vague memory of someone showing a way to do this in management studio but I do not recall how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable update cascade on the foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE t_Table_Language DROP CONSTRAINT FK_t_Table_Language_t_Table
ALTER TABLE t_Table_Language ADD CONSTRAINT FK_t_Table_Language_t_Table
FOREIGN KEY (funID) REFERENCES t_Table(funID)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

EDIT:
Or the other way around, i'm not sure which table has the foreing key

```
ALTER TABLE t_Table DROP CONSTRAINT FK_t_Table_Language_t_Table
ALTER TABLE t_Table ADD CONSTRAINT FK_t_Table_Language_t_Table
FOREIGN KEY (funID) REFERENCES t_Table_Language(funID)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Then do the update on the referenced table (the master table).

```
UPDATE t_Table_Language 
SET funID = 'References'
WHERE funID = 'Referencies'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No way of doing this without altering the table?

Comment: As far as I know to enable update cascade you need to drop the foreign key and recreate it.